# How to get DataTable from JSON string that contains an empty array using JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

(Json.NET) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>()` works with a populated array but, not with an empty array ( `[],` as seen in my example: jsonString2 → col2 ). I would like it to create a string[] column by default, or skip, or otherwise avoid the exception.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code (Update 1: Removed extra comma after col3 and still getting exception.):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSerializeEmptyArray()
{
    var jsonString1 = @"[
        {
            ""col1"": ""bd3013bb-39a3-4704-b7c9-803c220f8abe"",
            ""col2"": [
            ""57ae6e0e-0c20-4da5-a246-b949c71ef551"",
            ""2bafe349-4b29-4161-814a-5a369459b78c""
                ],
            ""col3"": ""b2c172ea-e48c-4e20-9bee-3470278bd801""
        }]";
    var test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString1);

    var jsonString2 = @"[
        {
            ""col1"": ""bd3013bb-39a3-4704-b7c9-803c220f8abe"",
            ""col2"": [],
            ""col3"": ""b2c172ea-e48c-4e20-9bee-3470278bd801""
        }]";
    var test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString2);
}
```

Exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: EndArray. Path '[0].col2', line 4, position 12.
>     Source=Newtonsoft.Json
>     StackTrace:
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.GetColumnDataType(JsonReader reader)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.GetColumnDataType(JsonReader reader)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.CreateRow(JsonReader reader, DataTable dt, JsonSerializer serializer)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)

Update 1: @D-Shih I removed the extra comma after col3 to make that "Json Parser" happy but, I still get the same exact Exception. Note that I do not get any error on `test1` but I do get the error on `test2`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error from your test JSON data. remove the comma after `col3`

```
 ""col3"": ""b2c172ea-e48c-4e20-9bee-3470278bd801""
```

instead of

```
 ""col3"": ""b2c172ea-e48c-4e20-9bee-3470278bd801"",
```

I would recommed a website can easy check JSON format

[Json Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

**EDIT**

I saw the `Json.net` source code

If you want to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` as `DataTable`, you can't give it. an empty `array`

on source code

```
private static void CreateRow(JsonReader reader, DataTable dt)
```

there is a part of code `Type columnType = GetColumnDataType(reader);` to get json colunm type, if you didn't provide a type `Json.net` can't judgment type of this array.

So you can give the array as an empty string.

look like this.

```
var jsonString2 = @"[
{
    ""col1"": ""bd3013bb-39a3-4704-b7c9-803c220f8abe"",
    ""col2"": [""""],
    ""col3"": ""b2c172ea-e48c-4e20-9bee-3470278bd801""
}]";
```

c# online:https://dotnetfiddle.net/M6A3vE

---

**EDIT1**

This is an issue, I report to `JSON.Net` it will be fix in future version

[Fix error when deserializing empty array in DataTable](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1786)

Comment: That did not fix it. I removed the extra comma after col3 to make that "Json Parser" happy but, I still get the same exact Exception. Note that I do not get any error on `test1` but I do get the error on `test2`. (I added screenshot to my original question.)

Comment: I saw `json.net`  source code you can see my edit answer.

Comment: The problem with the updated answer is: Although it does get a datatype of string[] successfully, it does so at the cost of requiring to "manipulate" the original json AND adding incorrect data of an empty string to the resulting DataTable. The extra comma I had after col3 was a fat finger in my example but empty arrays will be an expected unfortunate part of an api's json results.

Comment: @StevenLyon This is an issue, I report to `JSON.Net` it will be fix in future version